# validation falure

Tags: trigger, validation, lead-conversion

I am getting following error.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20025: 
ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.SACCESS", line 1295
ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CACCESS", line 2438
ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CACCESS", line 2369
ORA-06512:

Could you please help me what is this actually?

Comment: We get fatal errors from the underlying oracle database very rarely, something had to go seriously wrong. Your best action would be to contact Salesforce support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see the names of the seven dwarfs, 'DOPEY' in this case, then you know the problem us further down the stack, and is unlikely to be an issue with your code directly. It could be something you're doing that's causing it and it's not properly handled, or it could be something else entirely, but either way it'll be a case for the support team to investigate and resolve.

Comment: Yes. Smurfs = bad.